# Identifying Files with Matching names using Two For Loops

Tags: powershell

I have one folder with both XML and PDF files in it. I need each XML to have a PDF with a matching name and vice versa. I'm trying to create two loops, one just capturing the PDFs in the folder and another just getting the XMLs and then compare both of them to determine which have matches and which don't.

I have tried creating two separate For Each Loops with If statements inside them. I was hoping this would cycle through the names for both the XMLs and PDFs but I don't think it is. Please see code below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$Folder = "E:\Monitoring\CCRChannels\Delivery\"

$XMLFiles = Get-ChildItem $Folder -Filter "*.xml" 
$PDFFiles = Get-ChildItem $Folder -Filter "*.pdf" 

foreach($XMLfile in $XMLFiles) {

$XMLname = $XMLfile.name  

if($XMLfile.name -eq $PDFfile.name) {
 Write-Host "$XMLname has a matching PDF" -ForegroundColor Green
  }
Else {
 Write-Host "$XMLname does not have a matching PDF" -ForegroundColor Red
 }
    }


foreach($PDFfile in $PDFFiles) {
$PDFname = $PDFfile.name
if($PDFfile.name -eq $XMLfile.name) {
Write-Host "$PDFname has a matching XML" -ForegroundColor Green
  }
Else {
Write-Host "$PDFname does not have a matching XML" -ForegroundColor Red
  }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) properly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right you don't need multiple loops. This should be enough:

```
$Folder = 'E:\Monitoring\CCRChannels\Delivery'
$AllFileList = Get-ChildItem $Folder 
$XMLFiles = $AllFileList | Where-Object -Property Extension -EQ -Value '.xml'
$PDFFiles = $AllFileList | Where-Object -Property Extension -EQ -Value '.PDF'

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $XMLFiles -DifferenceObject $PDFFiles -Property BaseName -IncludeEqual
```

Comment: Apologies I should have mentioned this in my initial post. My reasoning behind the loops is to notify the user of each instance where an XML doesn't have an accompanying PDF. By notifying I mean by email but I was using Write-Host above to get it working before moving onto email.

Comment: You can easily use the output of `Compare-Object` for further steps. You'd use the property `SideIndicator` as the condition to decide if an email should be sent. ‍♂️

Comment: I'm getting errors if the ReferenceObject or DifferenceObject variable is null. Is there an easy way to stop this happening?

Comment: If there is a chance for either one variable to be empty you should check that before you continue to the comparison. ‍♂️